# Making script read a CSV and output answer

Tags: csv, powershell

I am looking to add a line(s) into a PowerShell script. I want to get my script to check if something exists in a CSV it will give a true/false response.

Basically I have a script to remove user access from O365 and AD including and mailbox changes.

My company also uses a lot of external portals which need removing manually.

I would like it to check the `$EmailAddress` input against CSV's (i.e `DomainHostAccess.CSV`, `WebsiteHostAccess.CSV`, `SupplierAccess.Csv`) then if there name is in the list it will output something similar to;

```
DomainHostAccess | True
WebsiteHostAccess | False
SupplierAccess | True
```

that way we know that we need to manually log into these services and remove accounts.

I have looked on the posts on here already and couldn't find anything suitable, I am fairly new to PS and this is a little advance for me so I would appreciate any help that can be given.

Comment: Hi Peter and welcome to SO, we are not suppose to write your code, try to create it and when you have something we can try and help you from there...

Comment: Have a look at this link http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2010/01/powershell-basics-1-reading-and-parsing-csv/

Comment: Can you at least show us what the csv files look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
$UserList = Import-Csv -Path C:\EmailAddress.CSV
$UserData = Import-Csv -Path C:\DomainHostAccess.CSV

ForEach ($Email in $UserList)
{

    $userMatch = $UserData | where {$_.Name -like $Email.Name}
    If($userMatch)
    {
        Write-host $Email.Name "Domain Access True"
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-host $Email.Name "Domain Access False"
    }

}
```

You would need to have headers on your CSVs for this check to work.